# WorldPay Apple Pay SDK unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, applepay, worldpay

I am trying to make a payment via Apple pay using world pay and their SDK HERE https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-ios. Within my app this payment is done via a notification, the user clicks on the notification, my app opens and the apple pay view is presented.

When I try to make my payment request (follow code below) with this line

```
let request = wp.createPaymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: ApplePaySwagMerchantID)
```

However my app crashes with:

```
2017-03-30 20:38:20.026378 CarGo[757:79619] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Worldpay createPaymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1740fea00'
```

I'm not really sure what could be causing this or how to go about debugging it?

my complete method which runs in the app delegate:

```
func makePayment(locationString: String){

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        let topWindow: UIWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        topWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        topWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
        topWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let wp: Worldpay = Worldpay.sharedInstance();
        wp.clientKey = "xxxxxxx";
        wp.reusable = true;


        let request = wp.createPaymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: ApplePaySwagMerchantID)
        request?.supportedNetworks = SupportedPaymentNetworks
        request?.countryCode = "GB"
        request?.currencyCode = "GBP"
        request?.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS

        var decimalValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: defaults.string(forKey: locationString))

        decimalValue = decimalValue.multiplying(by: 100)

        self.transactionsDescription = "Toll Payment: " + locationString
        self.transactionCost = decimalValue.intValue

        request?.paymentSummaryItems = [
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Toll Payment: " + locationString, amount:NSDecimalNumber(string: defaults.string(forKey: locationString)))
        ]

        let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request!)
        applePayController.delegate = self

        topWindow.rootViewController?.present(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

My bridge header file:

```
#import "Worldpay.h"
#import "APMController.h"
#import "WorldpayAPMViewController.h"
#import "ThreeDSController.h"
#import "WorldpayCardViewController.h"
#import "Worldpay+ApplePay.h"
```

Comment: Which version of the WorldPay SDK are you using? I'm having trouble finding the WorldPay class you're using in the documentation here: https://worldpayus.github.io/ipc_sdk_ios/

Comment: @mark https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-ios

Comment: Where did you find the signature for `wp.createPaymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: ApplePaySwagMerchantID)`? Was it autocompleted by Xcode? The guide to working with ObjC classes suggests `wp.createPaymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier(ApplePaySwagMerchantID)`. Reference, Working With Methods: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35

Comment: 'createPaymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier' has been renamed to 'createPaymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier:)'

Comment: @ZacPowell out of interest how did you test Apple Pay payments on your WorldPay testing environment? I can't add the WorldPay test card details to my wallet on my phone :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have found the issue. Have you included the following import in your Objective-C Bridging Header?

```
import "Worldpay+ApplePay.h"
```

This is a category that extends the `WorldPay` class with methods related to Apple Pay, and likely contains the method in question.

EDIT:

Make sure to include the `-ObjC` linker flag in your project's `Other Linker Flags` property in the `Build Settings`.

Comment: You might also need to add the `-ObjC` linker flag, outlined in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26124317/797767

Comment: You've got the `-ObjC` linker flag added to your project as well?

Comment: Dam linker flag some how went walk about!

Comment: I'll update the answer to include the linker flag as well. Glad it fixed your issue!